# Command-line action server interface?

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Rossers,

Is there an easy command-line way to call an action server?  Like... rosaction actionserver goal?

Dan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10845/command-line-action-server-interface?/) by [Dang](https://answers.ros.org/users/690/dang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a simpler (hackier) solution than `rosh`, you could actually use

```
> rostopic pub [action_ns]/goal [action_type]ActionGoal [fill in fields here]
```

This will send a goal message directly to the action server.  The action server has been designed to handle goals from "dumb action clients", such as `rostopic pub`.  You don't even have to bother filling in the header goal_id fields in the message.

---

Originally posted by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) with karma: 760 on 2011-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shubhamv](https://answers.ros.org/users/40644/shubhamv/) on 2019-03-29**:
An example please...

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-09-07**:
Type `rostopic pub [your_action]/goal`  and press tab to auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a true command line interface to send a goal, besides rostopic pub, but there are light-weight GUI tools for both action clients and action servers:

- Client: `rosrun actionlib axclient.py`
- Server `rosrun actionlib axserver.py`

Hopefully, these suit your needs.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-11-24**:
Does not work when connecting on a SSH a machine that has no X server!

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-02-17**:
Remember to set `$ROS_MASTER_URI` and `$ROS_IP` when using this with an action server running on another computer.  Not sure why that is necessary, since I can `rostopic pub` and `rostopic echo` without setting `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP`...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use rosh as an interactive command line for calling actions.  It supports tab-completion and uses Python syntax.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosh

You will need to load the 'rosh_common' plugin to support actions

e.g.

> > actions.add_two_ints()

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-11-24**:
I cannot find any `rosh` package, where is it?

**Comment by [troniak](https://answers.ros.org/users/36036/troniak/) on 2018-06-22**:
Looks like it's been deprecated since Kinetic